# SQL Server 2005 column not visible at asp.net mvc4 controller

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-4, edmx, edmx-designer

I am using ASP.NET MVC4 and SQL Server 2005 to develop a web application. Everything is working fine but I got stuck at a point. I updated my table with a new column `NO_Person` and updated my `.edmx` file. That updated column is showing up in the `.edmx` designer page but when I am trying to access that field at controller side its not showing in pop suggestion window and getting error

> table does not contain definition of field NO_Person

I updated my library.dll file and tried to rebuild my project, but getting same error.

Any suggestion please help.

Comment: seems like the underlying classes generated by edmx is not getting updated or regenerated.

Comment: Any suggestion what to do for this problem

Comment: You can use Update Model Wizard which should take care of this. However there are few things you need to take care when updating it. Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716700.aspx

Comment: i updated my model many times even i deleted the edmx file and reattached it but getting the same problem.

Comment: I tried this on new ASP.NET project and i am getting updates from database but on my existing project not showing any update from database.

Comment: Finally i solved this problem. The problem was in "EntityFramework" package in library part of project. i removed and install that package again and its working fine now.

Comment: I am happy your issue have been resolved. thanks for posting the fix :)